# Java Retrieve or Remove a value from TreeMap

Tags: java

I have a problem retrieving a Student's info from a list, or deleting it... Heelp... Code below:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Directory
{
    private TreeMap<String, Student> studentList;
    private int numberOfEntries;

    public Directory()
    {
        studentList = new TreeMap<String, Student>();
        numberOfEntries = 0;
    }

    public void addStudent(Student newStudent)
    {
        studentList.put(newStudent.StudentInfo(), newStudent);
        //numberOfEntries++;
    }

    public void StudentInfo(String StudentInfo)
    {
        Object obj = studentList.get(StudentInfo);
        System.out.println(obj);
    }

    public void removeStudent(String StudentInfo)
    {
        Object obj = studentList.remove(StudentInfo);
        System.out.println(obj + "Removed");
    }


    public void printStudentList()
    {
        System.out.println("List of Students: " + studentList.keySet());
    }
}
```

======= Student class ======== (Persons contains first, last & email)

```
public class Student extends Persons
{
    private String Sclass;

    public Student(String Lname, String Fname, String Email, String Sclass)
    {
        super(Lname, Fname, Email);
        this.Sclass = Sclass;
    }

    public String StudentInfo()
    {
        return " Full Name " + Lastname + " " + Firstname + "\n" + 
               "E-Mail: " + Email + "\n" +
               "Class Attending: " + Sclass;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return Lastname;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is not happening that you think should happen? Have you written test code for this? And, can you follow the Java naming standards: `StudentInfo` is not a good name for a method. Also, `numberOfEntries` is unnecessary since you can always ask the map for its size.

Comment: ↑↑ also applies to argument names in methods. Lname Fname Email is not good either.

Comment: When I run it n try to get the info for one particular student I get "null", same when I try to remove. And sorry, meant to delete numberOfEntries, just saturated with this.

Answer (score 2):

I could try and debug this for you, but that would defeat the purpose.  (This is *your* homework ... and the purpose is for *you* to learn how to do this yourself.)

My advice is as follows:

1. **FIRST** fix the style errors:

   - The names of variables should *always* start with a lower-case letter ... unless they are `static` `final` constants.
   - The names of methods should *always* start with a lower-case letter
   - Method and variable names should also be meaningful and consistent.  For instance:

     ```
     public void  removeStudent(String StudentInfo)
     ```

     Here `StudentInfo` actually needs to a student name, not a "student info" string as created by the `StrudentInfo` method ...

     Another example: `lname` and `fname` are not meaningful.  (I can guess what they mean, but that is *not good enough*.)
2. Create yourself a tester program that created instances of those classes and performs a sequence of tests on them.  Start with simple things, then move on the more complicated ones.

   (In the real world, we'd set up a more formal set of "unit tests" ... but you are probably not ready for that yet.

---

In fact, if you choose more meaningful names, and then look *carefully* at how those names are used, your error should "leap out and hit you on the nose".

But you will get maximum benefit if you go through the process yourself.